# Difference between TryInvokeMember and TryInvoke

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic, tryinvokemember

This is part of `DynamicObject` class:

```
public class DynamicObject : IDynamicMetaObjectProvider
{ 
    ...
    public virtual bool TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
    {
      result = (object) null;
      return false;
    }
    ...
    public virtual bool TryInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
    {
      result = (object) null;
      return false;
    }
}
```

From MSDN:
`TryInvoke`: Provides the implementation for operations that invoke an object
`TryInvokeMember`: Provides the implementation for operations that invoke a member

I want to know the **real** difference between this two methods because they have almost the same syntax and implementation. I already know that TryInvoke if for objects or  delegates, and TryInvokeMember is for methods, but why two methods for this? A good example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The documentation isn't really clear, but the examples for [TryInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487395%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [TryInvokeMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487539%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  show the difference.  `TryInvoke` is called when invoking the object (that is treating it like a delegate) and `TryInvokeMember` is used when invoking a method on the object.

The example below is derived from the MSDN samples:

```
dynamic number;
....
// Invoking an object. 
// The TryInvoke method is called.
number(2, "Two");

// Calling a method
// The TryInvokeMember method is called.
number.Clear();
```

The implementations you are showing are the same because they are both null implementations.  Returning false means that the method that is trying to be called is not implemented.

If there was a non-null implementation the difference would be that `TryInvokeMember` would examine the `binder.Name` property to determine which method would be called, while that would not be set for `TryInvoke`.

Answer (score 1):

also

Console.WriteLine(number); // will invoke an object , and the TryInvoke method is called